# How to make a cell return a number if in another cell I input a certain number from a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

First of all, English is not my native language so explaining what I need is tricky.

So I have product that can have a range of widths. Depending on the width of the product, the aquisition price changes.

How can I make a cell where I input a width (in numbers), and depending on the range that that number is, another cell returns a certain price.

So let's say that the price for a product with widhts between 0-1000mm is 5 dollars. I want to introduce a product with a width of 500mm in a cell, and the next cell should output a price of 5 dollars.

And then let's say I want to add a product of 1300mm, and the price from 1000mm-2000mm is 10 dollars. So I would input 1300mm in a cell, and another cell should output 10 dollars.

Is that possible in excel?
Please help!

Comment: Please have a look at this formula: `=IF(A1<1000;5;IF(AND(A1 >=1000; A1<2000);10))`

Comment: Start with a table of prices. In each case, use just the lower boundary for the widths in the range, for example 0 > $5, 1001 > $10. Then you can use VLOOKUP or a similar function to easily return the price for any width using an inexact match (in VLOOKUP< set the last argument to True to do this). This is a text book example of using a lookup with inexact matching to find a value within a range and return a second value for it.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdamV said.....

1. Create a table of your price list.
   The Max column isn't needed, but helps you keep an eye on the range.
   [image: Price List]
2. Select a cell within the table and press `Ctrl+T` to turn it into an Excel table.
   Note that the *Table Design* ribbon will appear and you can rename the table.
   [image: Price List as a table]
3. Use either formula:
   `=XLOOKUP($H$2,Table1[Min],Table1[Price],,-1)` or
   `=VLOOKUP(H2,Table1,3,TRUE)`
   [image]

The -1 in XLOOKUP and TRUE in VLOOKUP is "exact match, if none found return the next smaller item".

You could also keep the data as just a range of cells, but the formula won't automatically extend as you enter new price ranges.

**Edit:**  You could also use `=INDEX(Table1[Price],MATCH(H2,Table1[Min],1))`

Answer (score 0):

New here - but wanted to add something that could be helpful. In the newer versions of excel there is an `IFS` function. This function was created so you don’t have to nest `IF` functions like have been proposed as solutions here. `IFS` function allow you to evaluate a series of `IF` functions.

I’ll give it a go now but please take reference YouTube to verify.

```
=IFS(A8<1000,5),(A8>1000&A8<2000,10),(IF logic #3))
```